# How to get google sheets api append response?

Tags: javascript, google-sheets-api

I hope someone can help.  I am trying to append to google sheets.  However, it does not seem to work.  "get" works fine. Do I need to re-authorize to make the google sheet writable? (I am just programming for fun, and making web app for my own use.) Here are some of my code.  I can't get any responses either.  Thanks

```
    gapi.client.sheets.spreadsheets.values.append({
          spreadsheetId: 'spreadsheetId',
          range: 'sheet1!A:E',
          valueInputOption: 'RAW',
          insertDataOption: 'INSERT_ROWS',
          resource : {
            "range": "Sheet1!A:E",
            "majorDimension": "ROWS",
            "values": [
                [
                    "2018-01-01",
                    2,
                    3,
                    4
                ]
            ],
          }
        }).then(function(response) {
        var result = response.result;
        console.log(`${result.updates.updatedCells} cells appended.`)
//      appendPre('Your Balance is ' + response.result.values);
      }, function(response) {
        appendPre('error: ' + reason.result.error.message);

      });
```

Comment: Please include whether or not your `console.log` or any error is being printed. Also details about what comes back in the `response` object

Comment: @Ricky Nguyen Did my answer show you the result what you want? Would you please tell me about it? That is also useful for me to study. If this works, other people who have the same issue with you can also base your question as a question which can be solved. If you have issues for my answer yet, I apologize. At that time, can I ask you about your current situation? I would like to study to solve your issues.

Comment: @Ricky Nguyen You told me that the script worked by a comment. But you deleted the comment. Can I ask you about it? If my answer was not useful for your situation. I have to apologize and modify it. If you can cooperate to resolve your issue, I'm glad. I would like to think of about the solution.

Answer (score 0):

How about this modification?

#### Modification points:

- Reason of `I can't get any responses either.` is `reason.result.error.message`. In your script, `response` is used in the function.
- In your script, there is an issue at the request body. About this, you can see a sample script of the values.append method at [here](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/append). In this modification, your objects are used with the sample script.

#### Modified script:

```
const params = {
  spreadsheetId: 'spreadsheetId',
  range: 'Sheet1!A:E',
  valueInputOption: 'RAW',
  insertDataOption: 'INSERT_ROWS',
};
const valueRangeBody = {
  "range": "Sheet1!A:E",
  "majorDimension": "ROWS",
  "values": [["2018-01-01", 2, 3, 4]],
};
gapi.client.sheets.spreadsheets.values.append(params, valueRangeBody)
.then(function(response) {
  console.log(response.result);
}, function(reason) {
  console.error('error: ' + reason.result.error.message);
});
```

#### Note:

- This modified script supposes that you can use Sheets API and you can also use the values.append method.

#### Reference:

- [spreadsheets.values.append](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/append)

Although I could confirm that this script worked in my environment, if this didn't work in your environment, I apologize.